# How to avoid "PeerDiscoveryException" when running RSK node on Windows?

Tags: port, json-rpc, rsk

I started running RSK node on Windows and when I tried:

```sh
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:4444
```

I always get:

```json
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x0"}
```

This obviously means that my node is not syncing,
so I checked the logs and found `Address already in use`:

```
 Exception in thread "UDPServer" co.rsk.net.discovery.
 PeerDiscoveryException: Discovery can't be started.
 At co.rsk.net.discovery.UDPServer$1.run(UDPServer.java:65) - caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use...
```

I do not have any other RSK instance running,
so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 6):

You need to change your peer discovery port (`peer.port`)
to use a different one.
This is because RSK Mainnet uses `5050` as default peer discovery port
and Windows usually has smaller port numbers already assigned for other uses.

For example, to start RSKj with a peer discovery port of `50506`,
use the following command:

```sh
java \
  -D peer.port=50506 \
  -cp <PATH-TO-THE-RSKJ-JAR> \
  co.rsk.Start \
  --regtest
```

You may also choose to set `peer.port=50506` in the relevant config file.

NOTE: This issue does not usually occur on RSK Testnet
because its default peer discovery port is `50505`,
a much larger port number.
This issue usually does not occur on other operating systems
because that RSK Mainnet port number is typically unused.